# Github page does not work it only shows me the repository name

Tags: html, github-pages

I add a survey project to my github account and create a page for it but when i click the link they gave me which is this one: https://pascavld.github.io/Survey-/ it shows me the name of the repository instead of showing me the index.html and the style.css i added to the repository.What I did wrong?

Comment: can you share repository link

Comment: What is the page supposed to look like?

Comment: @dgknca The repository is https://github.com/Pascavld/Survey-

Comment: https://pascavld.github.io/Survey-/survey/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You created another directory before your index.html file. The correct link is https://pascavld.github.io/Survey-/survey/